# Install the latest boost centos 5.5

Tags: centos, installation

How can I install the latest boost in centos 5.5? Like what commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version of boost officially shipped and supported with CentOS 5.5 is 1.33.1-10 but you can get an rpm of boost-1.40.0-10 at the [BlackOp repo](http://blackopsoft.com/). Install at your own risk; instructions for using the repo are at the site.

Answer (score 0):

I have had success installing Boost 1.41 as follows:

```
yum remove boost-devel boost
yum install boost141 boost141-devel boost141-program-options boost141-regex boost141-thread boost141-system
ln -s /usr/include/boost141/boost /usr/include
```