# Install the latest boost centos 5.5

Tags: boost, centos

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Install the latest boost centos 5.5](https://serverfault.com/questions/204492/install-the-latest-boost-centos-5-5)

How can I install the latest boost in centos 5.5? Like what commands.

Thanks!

Comment: What version of boost is available in the repos (`yum info libbost`) and what version do you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running something like this (from terminal and via **sudo** or **su** of course):

> yum install libboost libboost-dev

or

> yum install boost boost-devel boost-doc

And anytime you can download boost sources and perform

> ./configure && make && sudo make install

Comment: This will work, but be warned--if there are files placed on your system by `sudo make install` that are not in the original package, they will not be removed when you uninstall the original boost RPM.

Comment: Also be warned that installing Boost through yum will not provide the latest version of Boost as posed in the original question. Also, Boost uses `bjam install`, not `./configure && make && sudo make install`.